# Inserir apenas dado preenchido do array PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela, e fiz um loop for para ela receber `input` e também para fazer insert, porém estou tendo problemas no `INSERT` e `UPDATE`. Onde tenho dois campos `codigo_tipo`,`descricao` que são inseridos sempre juntos ao campo `codigo_produto`, Mas, um codigo de produto pode ter N tipos e descrições como pode ter apenas 1.

Logo se eu preencho só a primeira linha, as demais são enviadas em branco para o banco de dados, como faço para que sejam enviadas somente as linhas preenchidas para o banco e as mesmas sofram update depois se eu quiser altera-las.

index.php

```
<form action='salvar.php' method='POST'>
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod"; 
        $resulta = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();
    ?>
    <div class='form-group col-lg-4'>
        <label>  <b>Código do Produto:</b> </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="6"  name="codigo_produto" value="<?php $row['codigo_produto'] ?>"><br><br>
    </div>

    <table border="2"><!-- Iniciando a Tabela -->

        <thead>
            <tr><!-- Início dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>                                                                                                              
            </tr><!-- Fim dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <?php
            include("conn.php");

            for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ //coloquei este valor para testar                  

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='codigo_tipo[]' id='codigo_tipo[]' style='border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;'</td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='descricao[]' id='descricao[]' value='' style='border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;'</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>

    </table><br>

    <div class='form-group col-lg-3'><!-- Inicio Botão para efetuar registro no Banco de Dados -->
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="enviar_tipo" value="Salvar Informações">
    </div>

</form>
```

salvar.php

```
<?php
include("conn.php");

if(isset($_POST['enviar_tipo'])){

    $codigo_produto = $_POST['codigo_produto'];
    $codigo_tipo = $_REQUEST['codigo_tipo'];
    $descricao = $_REQUEST['descricao'];

    $sql_tipo = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto' ";
    $resulta = $conn->query($sql_tipo);
    $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();

for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['codigo_tipo'])AND($_POST['descricao']); $i++) {

if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) {
    $result_produto = "UPDATE tipoprod SET codigo_tipo = '$codigo_tipo[$i]', descricao = '$descricao[$i]' WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto' ";
} else {
    $result_produto = "INSERT INTO tipoprod (codigo_produto, codigo_tipo, descricao) VALUES ('$codigo_produto', '$codigo_tipo[$i]', '$descricao[$i]')";
}

    $resultado_produto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produto);
    echo "$result_produto <br>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: utilize array_filter

Comment: como eu adaptaria isso neste código? tem algum link para eu ter uma base, sou iniciante em php

Comment: exemplo $arrayLimpo = array_filter($codigo_tipo);

Comment: https://ideone.com/sMzJK0

Comment: declaro o array filter dentro do for ou fora,  sei que tem de ser no salvar.php mas estou meio perdido

Comment: $codigo_tipo e $descricao são os que podem ter valores nulos certo?

Comment: sim, correto obrigado pelo comentario, vou tentar implementar no meu código

Comment: $codigo_tipo = array_filter($_REQUEST['codigo_tipo']);

Comment: esse seu include("conn.php"); na index não está no lugar errado não?

Comment: Ele faz conexão com o banco de dados, o arquivo conn.php

Comment: sim eu sei, ele deveria estar antes da linha $sql = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod";

Comment: Se você coloca Código do Produto = 3 e preenche 2 linhas Código e Descrição e esse codigo de produto  (3) não existe na tabela ele insere 2 linhas com mesmo codigo de produto. Dai da proxima vez se vc colocar codigo de produto 3 e preencher varias linhas ele vai fazer update em todas as linhas da tabela com codigo = 3 pelos valores da ultima linha do formulario

Comment: Mas é isso mesmo que eu quero,  se a pessoa inserir 5 tipos e descrição, eles tem que ficar vinculados ao codigo do produto, e depois se quiserem alterar ao invés de adicionar elas teriam essa facilidade . obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar os nulos é assim

```
 $codigo_tipo = array_filter($_REQUEST['codigo_tipo']); 
 .........
 .........
 for($i = 0; $i<count($codigo_tipo)AND($_POST['descricao']); $i++) {
 .........
```

> array_filter — Filtra elementos de um array utilizando uma função callback, se nenhum callback é fornecido, todas entradas de array iguais a FALSE serão removidas.

Exemplo array_filter() sem callback

```
$entry = array(
         0 => 'foo',
         1 => false,
         2 => -1,
         3 => null,
         4 => ''
      );

print_r(array_filter($entry));
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
Array
(
  [0] => foo
  [2] => -1
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, fiz lá e deu certo cara valeu mesmo. Porém se eu seleciono o valor que eu preenchi depois de inserir ele não faz update estranho

Comment: Quando é somente um tipo e descricao ele insere e faz update, mas quando são 3 tipos e descricao vinculados a um produto ele só insere e depois se eu quero alterar somente a primeira linha ele da update nas 3

Comment: Então no caso se inserir apenas 1 tipo e descrição vinculados a um código de produto ele insere e altera, porém se eu vinculo 3 tipos e descrições a um código de produto ele apenas insere e quando tento fazer update ele altera todos tipos e descrições, ou se tento inserir mais uma linha depois de inserir apenas uma no banco ele entende que a segunda linha faz update na primeira e não insere

Comment: @VictorT. eu atentei para esse detalhe em um comentário lá na sua pergunta. Isso já é um caso a ser resolvido na estrutura da tabela, no INSERT e no UPDATE. Talvez um WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto' AND .....

Comment: WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto' AND codigo_tipo = '$codigo_tipo' ?

Comment: então, teria que ter algo único para cada registro e colocar na clausula where do update para não afetar todos eles. Do jeito que está `WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto'` faz update em todos os registros onde  codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto'` Algo assim, WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto' AND isso = '$isso'

Comment: obrigado vou tentar consertar meu update